# Text classification

Tags: classification, text-mining, svm

I am using SVM algorithm for text classification. I need to know where can I find twitter dataset and how can I use it in weka tool or any other tool?

Comment: The best way to collect data from a website is by building a webcrawler that way you can customize what you take out of the HTML page as you may need it.

Comment: Twitter Provide [Api](https://dev.twitter.com/) which can be used to collect data from twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has rules that limit sharing of complete datasets, instead limiting sharing to the tweet ids (see this [discussion](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-and-open-data-in-academia/51934) and the [developer agreement](https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/agreement-and-policy)).  Tools such as [twarc](https://github.com/DocNow/twarc) can be used to "rehydrate" the tweet metadata by calling the Twitter api and retrieving the info.  The Twitter API has rate limiting which can make this a somewhat slow process.

For a package that works in R, see [RTextTools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTextTools/index.html) or check out [RWeka](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html) which bridges the gap between R and Java to use Weka.  If using Python, you can also use scikit-learn's svm implementation.

Answer (score 0):

These are a few sites I found for that. I am not an R programmer so I don't know any Weka tools and how to use them but hope this helps. You can find them [here](http://www.sananalytics.com/lab/twitter-sentiment/sanders-twitter-0.2.zip) and [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Twitter+Data+set+for+Arabic+Sentiment+Analysis).

Answer (score 0):

This collection of [twitter datasets](https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/top-20-twitter-datasets-for-natural-language-processing-and-machine-learning/) might help you find the dataset you're looking for. Mainly sentiment analysis datasets, but moderation and classification datasets too.